# How To Redirect To Another page in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I Want To redirect To List Page of My Application From App Component After Saving Data ...
history.push("/List") not Working...
Below Is my Code.. Please Help.

```
let history= useHistory();
 let SaveData=(props)=>{
 
    fetch('https://localhost:44345/api/Student/Save', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('admin:admin'),'Content-Type':'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
       "Name": props.name,
       "Age": props.age,
       "Gender": props.gender
       
      })
     }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.status);       
      if (response.ok) {
        alert('Data Saved succesfully');
        redirect();
      }
  })
  }

  function redirect() {
    history.push("/List")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNavigate` from `React-Router-Dom v6`.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  ...
  if (response.ok) {
    navigate('/list')
  }
}
```

Comment: export 'useNavigate' (imported as 'useNavigate') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Prompt, Redirect, Route, Router, StaticRouter, Switch, generatePath, matchPath, useHistory, useLocation, useParams, useRouteMatch, withRouter)

Comment: @KhanFaizan Do you use ```react-router-dom``` version 6?

Comment: No version  5.2.0

Comment: okay, what error do you got?

Comment: The same error I mentioned above when using navigate hook

Comment: you cannot get the same error as you don't use useNavigate in you question

Comment: What I mean is after using useNavigate..

Comment: Originally error was unknown type in promise

Comment: can you provide playground with your code or github repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242780/discussion-between-vladimir-trotsenko-and-khan-faizan).